# How to create bootable image of the entire OS for creating new EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, iso-image, amazon-ec2

I have a Linux OS installed on my local desktop. Is it possible to create a disk image of the entire OS (including all installed software and libraries and user files) and use it to create Amazon an EC2 instance similar to my local destop?

Comment: If you full-clone your desktop Linux and apply the image to an EC2 instance, it won't work because of many incompatible things, including hardware, kernel and boot information, etc.

Comment: @JakeGould I think it's possible if you don't blindly clone the raw disk, but only some (but not all) files and programs. Thar summarizes to "a partial, file-based clone may work".

Comment: It can be done if you convert live filesystem to `VMDK` (VMWare's virtual disk) then [import](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/) it to EC2. There're plenty examples [like this](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/virtualizing-a-physical-linux-machine/) how to convert  Linux system from physical machine to VMDK image.

Answer (score 0):

You could but that wouldn't be optimal and you would need to make sure it had all the needed drivers.

Better to get the list of the packages you installed on your local desktop, then install the packages ontop of an ami of the same os(just make sure to remove any drivers from the list of packages). That way it will have the correct drivers.

Which distro?

ubuntu 14+ 
apt list --installed
or
dpg -l

fedora/centos 
yum or dnf list installed
or
rpm -qa